# Unobtrusive client validation is not working when the form contains hidden input field

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, unobtrusive-validation

I have a model like:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
}
```

And the view:

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.Student

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Student", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div >
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstMidName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstMidName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstMidName)
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The problem is that when I am rendering the view using Ajax Get using `return PartialView("Edit", student);` statement, the unobtrusive jQuery validation fails. The validation is working fine when I remove the hidden field `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)`.

I have used below code to render the view using Ajax Get request:

```
function ShowEditPartialView(sender) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Student/EditPartial",
        data: {
            id: courseid
        },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {

            $("#EditCoursePartial").html(data);

            ///because the page is loaded with ajax, the validation rules are lost, we have to rebind them:
            $('form').removeData('validator');
            $('form').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
        }
    });
}
```

Any idea on how it will be resolved.

Comment: Why do you need `jQuery.validator.defaults.ignore = ":hidden";`, it's by default?

Comment: It's not working even if I remove this. All I just want is my Jquery validation to work on this form.

Comment: Try adding `$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });` before the `parse('form')`.